# Incorrect results while using cts:element-range-query on last-modified property and how to bind external variables in XQuery

Tags: marklogic

I am creating an AdhocQuery as:**session.newAdhocQuery("cts:search(fn:collection(),cts:properties-query(cts:element-range-query(xs:QName(\"prop:last-modified\"),\"<\",current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration(\"P1D\"))))");**

value of current-dateTime : 2014-05-15T20:27:34.468+05:30

Still results are returned with last-modified date less than current date time.
Below are some sample results:

/content/1878818.doc 2014-05-12T19:59:16+05:30

/content/1878965.doc 2014-05-12T19:59:16+05:30

/content/1878105.doc 2014-05-12T19:55:48+05:30

And 1 more thing instead of current-dateTime() how can I use some other dateTime in an XQuery.

Thanks,

Poonam

Answer (score 2):

Your query will return documents "up to one day in the past", which includes the the values you see in your results, since they all occur before `xs:dateTime('2014-05-14T20:27:34.468+05:30')`.

To create xs:dateTime values, you can cast a string as a dateTime: `xs:dateTime('2014-05-12T19:59:16+05:30')` or by using a special 2-parameter constructor: [`fn:dateTime($arg1 as xs:date?, $arg2 as xs:time?)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-dateTime). There are dozens of helper functions in the spec for manipulating date and time values (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/). MarkLogic also has a built-in helper function called [`xdmp:parse-dateTime`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3aparse-dateTime) that simplifies this a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In query customization I am interested in using a local variable which will have some dateTime value stored in it.

So I am firing a query as specified below:
s has dateTime value.

session.newAdhocQuery("cts:search(fn:collection(),cts:properties-query(cts:element-range-query(xs:QName(\"prop:last-modified\"),\">\",xs:dateTime("+s+"))))");

But I am getting an exception like 

com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected AlmostNumeric_

So do will you please guide me on this customization.

Comment: @Poonam I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `xs:dateTime("+s+")`. However, this is probably unrelated to your current question and should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Basically I want compare last-modified date with a date value stored in a properties file instead of comparing it with hard-coded value. So here s has a date value read from properties file. I tried to use XQJ API of MarkLogic for binding external variables in XQuery. So now I am able to get content of the file but not any other metadata.

Yes you are correct, I should put this as a separate question.

Thanks.